# Firebase https.onCall runs fine but only returns {data: null}

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

My cloud function runs as expected until I try to return something back to the front-end. For both final log points D and G, I still only receive `{data:null}`, yet modifications to my databases etc, run perfectly fine.

I think I might be  incorrectly trying to return the function.

Thanks for your time, all help is appreciated.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

admin.initializeApp();

exports.accountSetUp = functions.https.onCall((data, context)=>{
  let validation = true;
  if (data.company == "" || data.company == null || data.company == undefined) {
    validation = false;
  }
  if (data.name == "" || data.name == null || data.name == undefined) {
    validation = false;
  }

  const expression = /^[^@]+@\w+(\.\w+)+\w$/;
  if (!expression.test(data.email)) {
    validation = false;
  }
  if (data.password.length < 8) {
    validation = false;
  }


  if (data.type == "employer" && validation == true) {
    const user = {
      email: data.email,
      emailVerified: false,
      password: data.password,
      displayName: data.name,
    };
    console.log("A");
    admin.auth().createUser(user
    ).then((userReturn) => {
      const companyDetails = {
        admin: userReturn.uid,
        company_name: data.company,
        signed: {
          sign: false,
          name: "",
          job: "",
          date: "",
          terms: "",
          signature: "",
        },
        profile: {
          size: "",
          location: "",
          logo: "",
          li: "",
          website: "",
          company_description: "",
        },
      };
      console.log("B");
      admin.database().ref("/employers").push(companyDetails)
          .then((companyReturn)=>{
            const userDetails={
              admin: true,
              manager_num: userReturn.uid,
              type: "employer",
              email: data.email,
              manager_name: data.name,
              profile: {
                job_title: "",
                phone: "",
                li: "",
                location: ""},
              company_num: companyReturn.key};

            console.log("C");
            admin.database().ref("/users/"+userReturn.uid).set(userDetails)
                .then(()=>{
                  console.log("d");
                  return ({result: "success"});
                }).catch((error)=>{
                  console.log("E");
                  return (error);
                });
          }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log("F");
            return (error);
          });

      // add to user database
      // add to company database
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log("G");
      return (error);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correctly return the chain of Promises, as shown below (see the `return`s and how the `then` and `catch` blocks are chained). This is key when calling back to back asynchronous methods which return Promises and you'll find some detailed explanations [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining).

```
exports.accountSetUp = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    let validation = true;
    if (data.company == "" || data.company == null || data.company == undefined) {
        validation = false;
    }
    if (data.name == "" || data.name == null || data.name == undefined) {
        validation = false;
    }

    const expression = /^[^@]+@\w+(\.\w+)+\w$/;
    if (!expression.test(data.email)) {
        validation = false;
    }
    if (data.password.length < 8) {
        validation = false;
    }


    if (data.type == "employer" && validation == true) {
        const user = {
            email: data.email,
            emailVerified: false,
            password: data.password,
            displayName: data.name,
        };
        console.log("A");

        return admin.auth().createUser(user)
            .then((userReturn) => {
                const companyDetails = {
                    admin: userReturn.uid,
                    company_name: data.company,
                    signed: {
                        sign: false,
                        name: "",
                        job: "",
                        date: "",
                        terms: "",
                        signature: "",
                    },
                    profile: {
                        size: "",
                        location: "",
                        logo: "",
                        li: "",
                        website: "",
                        company_description: "",
                    },
                };
                console.log("B");
                return admin.database().ref("/employers").push(companyDetails)
            })
            .then((companyReturn) => {
                const userDetails = {
                    admin: true,
                    manager_num: userReturn.uid,
                    type: "employer",
                    email: data.email,
                    manager_name: data.name,
                    profile: {
                        job_title: "",
                        phone: "",
                        li: "",
                        location: ""
                    },
                    company_num: companyReturn.key
                };

                console.log("C");
                return admin.database().ref("/users/" + userReturn.uid).set(userDetails)
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log("d");
                return ({ result: "success" });
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("E");
                // See the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
            });


    } else {
        // See the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are able, I have a different issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74099215/firebase-cloud-functions-error-unhandled-error-typeerror-cannot-read-propertie . Thanks