# FIrebase CLoud Functions Error: Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'database')

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have deployed a firebase cloud functon. However, when  call it I run into an error:

```
Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'database')
```

The error is in reference to the line

```
return admin.database().ref("/users/"+context.auth.uid).once("value")
```

Here is the entire function:

```
exports.termsAccept = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  let admin;
  let companyNum;
  console.log("/users/"+context.auth.uid);
  return admin.database().ref("/users/"+context.auth.uid).once("value")
      .then((snap)=>{
        admin = snap.val().admin;
        companyNum = snap.val().company_num;
        return admin.database().ref("/employers/"+companyNum).once("value");
      })
      .then((snap)=>{
        if (admin == true && snap.val().signed.sign == false ) {
          if (data.name !== "" && data.job !== "" && data.signature !== "") {
            const signed = {
              date: String(new Date()),
              job: data.job,
              name: data.name,
              sign: true,
              signature: data.signature,
              terms: data.terms,

            };

            return admin.database().ref("/employers/"+companyNum+"/signed")
                .set(signed);
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
        return (error);
      });
});
```

The `console.log` displays the correct location that I wish to access.

Thanks for your time, all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the presence of database link in "admin" setup.

Comment: Sorry I am not entirely sure what you mean. I have other functions on the script that use admin.database() perfectly fine. Although, all of the other uses are of .set and .push, as opposed to .once

Comment: look at the top of the code sniped

 let admin; 

you are supposed to import it I guess, but not to declare a variable.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. I had accidentally named a variable admin but had forgotten that the firebase admin already exists under the same name, so I have been overwriting it! good spot.

Comment: I'm glad I've helped ^^